# Returning Void in Async method from WEB API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, async-await, async-ctp

I have this async method inside ASP.NET MVC 4 WEB API Controller that I got from this blog:
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/html5-drag-and-drop-asynchronous-multi-file-upload-with-asp-net-webapi/

```
  public async Task<IList<RecivedFile>> Post()
    {
        List<RecivedFile> result = new List<RecivedFile>();
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            try
            {
                MultipartFormDataStreamProvider stream = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/USER-UPLOADS"));

                IEnumerable<HttpContent> bodyparts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(stream);
                IDictionary<string, string> bodyPartFiles = stream.BodyPartFileNames;
                IList<string> newFiles = new List<string>();

                foreach (var item in bodyPartFiles)
                {
                    var newName = string.Empty;
                    var file = new FileInfo(item.Value);

                    if (item.Key.Contains("\""))
                        newName = Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), item.Key.Substring(1, item.Key.Length - 2));
                    else
                        newName = Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), item.Key);

                    File.Move(file.FullName, newName);
                    newFiles.Add(newName);
                }

                var uploadedFiles = newFiles.Select(i =>
                {
                    var fi = new FileInfo(i);
                    return new RecivedFile(fi.Name, fi.FullName, fi.Length);
                }).ToList();

                result.AddRange(uploadedFiles);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My question is why exactly does this method have a return type of Task? It is not clear "where to" or "to whom" it returns this task? It's like there is no one that waits for/receives the returned object.

I wonder what will be the implications if I return void like this:

**EDIT:**

**I have tried the code below and it completely breaks the program. it's like the runtime looses the reference to the code, the code itself doesn't finish running.**

```
    public async void Post()
    {
        List<RecivedFile> result = new List<RecivedFile>();
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            try
            {
                MultipartFormDataStreamProvider stream = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/USER-UPLOADS"));

                IEnumerable<HttpContent> bodyparts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(stream);
                IDictionary<string, string> bodyPartFiles = stream.BodyPartFileNames;
                IList<string> newFiles = new List<string>();

                foreach (var item in bodyPartFiles)
                {
                    var newName = string.Empty;
                    var file = new FileInfo(item.Value);

                    if (item.Key.Contains("\""))
                        newName = Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), item.Key.Substring(1, item.Key.Length - 2));
                    else
                        newName = Path.Combine(file.Directory.ToString(), item.Key);

                    File.Move(file.FullName, newName);
                    newFiles.Add(newName);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ASP.NET runtime waits for it. You may find [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) useful.

Most examples for `async` assume a UI context. ASP.NET [also provides a context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), but it's a "request" context - one for each HTTP request. My [`async`/`await` post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) gives an overview of this "context", and the [`async`/`await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) goes into much more detail.

Comment: So the conclusion is to never return void in async methods when used in ASP.NET

Comment: There are a handful of situations in ASP.NET 4.5 where you can use an `async void` method - the runtime will detect it and react appropriately. But as a general rule, it's best to use `async Task` unless you really *have* to do `async void`.

Comment: since async void is essentially "fire and forget" there very rarely is a reason to do that. One example is the page_load in the new Web Forms - protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

With return type void you don't wait for an object to return.. You wait for an operation to finish. You wait for your **Task** to finish.

Comment: Not sure to whom you refer by saying "you" ("you don't wait"). I don't want to wait for anything. The point here that it is used in WEB API and I can't understand what exactly do you want me to wait for?

Answer (score 0):

If you return void, you will be returning 204 "No Content" Response message immediately regardless of the completion status of your asynchronous operation. This is done by the help of `VoidResultConverter`.

> Note: On RC, you will see that it returns 200 "OK" response but with
>   the RTM, it will return 204 "No Content" response.