# Asp.Net Web API, 'async Task' OR 'async void' as return type

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

I am creating a asp.net web API project. 
This will be a logging service.

The applications will use this service by making async calls. It is mainly "fire and forget" principle. I don't want any thing from the service to be returned. 
Now my question is should I create web-API methods with 'async Task' OR 'async void' as return type.

I was referring to this [Async/Await - Best practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: If you don't care about returning exceptions from the service, `async void` should work just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Void in Async method from WEB API Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915138/returning-void-in-async-method-from-web-api-controller)

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want any thing from the service to be returned.

An HTTP WebAPI must return something, at least a status code. That's how HTTP works.

> my question is should I create web-API methods with 'async Task' OR 'async void' as return type.

As described in [the referenced article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), you should avoid `async void`. You should only use `async void` for event handlers (or things that are logically event handlers). A controller action is not an event handler. Thus, you should use `async Task`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web.Http;
using AysncTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("api/cleardata/{id}/{requestId}/")]
        public async AysncTask ClearData(Guid id, Guid requestId)
        {
            try
            {
                await AysncTask.Run(() => DoClearData(id, requestId));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception in ClearData", ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

async Task of course - this make your server more scalable. [Here](https://youtu.be/cpsKlAKytrY?t=3301) J Richter explain why ( I think nobody can explain better).